# Confusion about reputation activity?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

When I review my reputation activity, I can see where I have downvoted posts & lost reputation. When I display the details asssociated the number matches the loss initially displayed

[image]

I noticed for one post I had a loss of 2 reputation but when I clicked to view the details it showed a gain of 2 reputation for an edit I had made.

[image]

**How should I interpret this and/or how did this occur?**

Comment: Possibly related on Webmasters Meta: [“Suggested edit approval overridden” from 5 years ago? But nothing changed?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/suggested-edit-approval-overridden-from-5-years-ago-but-nothing-changed)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yea, it's strange, my edit is still active on the post in question.

Comment: Try checking the "show removed posts" checkbox on the bottom of your reputation page.

Comment: @DonaldDuck that was it! I didn't realize removed posts were hidden by default. There was a post removed the same day netting a -2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking the "show removed posts" checkbox on the bottom of your reputation page (Credits: [Donald Duck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/349538/donald-duck)).

Also, removed posts are hidden by default. If there are posts removed the same day it could explain a net result for that day of `-2` (Credits: [Donald Peat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/296861/donald-peat)).